# Car heats up when stopped in traffic and cools down when I start driving

Tags: overheating, fan

The car is a 2002 Honda Accord and after about 20 minutes of driving the car starts heating up. The needle goes up all the way when I’m stopped, but as soon as I start driving it goes back to the middle. The fan is working. What is weird about the fan though is that even if my drive is relatively short about 10 min of driving and I turn the car off the fan stays on for a while.

I’m a computer guy not really good with cars so I wanted to ask here first before I go to a mechanic and get ripped off.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Check to ensure the fan relays are good ... usually when a car heats up when stopped, yet cools down when running, it leads right back to the fans, in one way or another.

Comment: Check that your radiator is full. I had this same issue with a low radiator on a 92 Accord.

Comment: Sad you assume that mechanics will automatically rip you off - is that based on your industry practice? However, you should check the thermostat or have it checked. Also have the radiator checked - is it blocked or partially blocked (leaves, paper etc)

Comment: @SolarMike - If it were blocked with debris, this would usually produce the opposite issue of overheating while going and cooling just fine when sitting still ... not a bad thing to check, anyway, just from my experience won't produce the same effects.

Comment: @paulster2 I found that ram-air gave sufficient cooling when the fan belt had broken... while pausing in traffic was causing overheating...

Comment: @SolarMike - Okay, but not sure what that has to do with a blocked radiator as you suggest in your previous comment? Your recent comment suggests pretty much what I'm sayinging ... the fan isn't working, yet cools when rolling due to air flow. The fan helps to ~35mph, then the air flow is more than what the fan can provide.